# How to lint C# in Sublime Text 2

Tags: c#, sublimetext2

I use SublimeLinter for Python, PHP etc. and was wondering whether C# linting / syntax checking was available as a plugin.

If not, what is the best way to go about making one? I have Visual Studio 2010 so is it a case of the plugin pointing at a checking program, or is it not that simple?

Also as a bonus, a list of other tools that make C# development in ST2 easier would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Sublime Text 2 already contains a codex for C# and it is well developed. If you want a plugin you'll have to look on their forums.